# AdapterView Anonymous Object

Tags: java, android, android-adapterview

I'm new to java and android. i don't understand this code

```
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

this's my guess : OnItemClickListener is an interface. we create an anonymous object from the class AdapterView.
i got information that AdapterView.OnItemClickListener is an interface from [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

is it right ?

Comment: Yes, basically. You create an anonymous class of type AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes essentially this mechanism gives you a way to specify a block of code that will get run whenever the event happens. In this case the event is an onItemClick() for a GridView. This pattern is used somewhat commonly on Android. You override the interface methods to do whatever you want, the system will call them when the action has taken place.

I would encourage you to explore some more common examples of this pattern in the Android APIs. Look at the javadocs for several of the View widgets, in particular the `public void setOn{ACTION}Listener()` There are many possible actions, click and touch are two common ones.

check out [android.wiget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) in the docs. There is a big list of interfaces near the top. Several of them are Listener interfaces similar to this.